# A Log-Normal looking distribution with a 'Nice' integration

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I have a Ph.D. student working on a theoretical paper where we have a  distribution that looks log-normal 'like'.  That is it has most of the mass in the front area then heads towards zero.  That's really the only requirement.  If the distribution actually hit zero that would be ok as well.  So he's been looking for a distribution that would result in a "simple" solution to the following:

d = $\int _0^{\infty }\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x-1}}f(x)dx$

Where $f(x)$ is the PDF.  The reason that the solution being simple is important is because $d$ will be substituted into a hamiltonian problem (and no, we don't have any specific values for $a$).  He's done the brute force approach of trying all of the following in Mathematica (in addition to lognormal):

- Gamma
- F-ratio
- Fréchet
- inverse Gaussian
- Nakagami
- Rayleigh
- Cauchy
- SkewNormal
- Exponential
- Beta
- Beta Prime
- ChiSquare
- InverseGamma
- Gompertz-Makeham
- Levy
- Pareto
- Weibull

I'm an IO theory guy, so this is not my strength.   If anyone has a suggestion to try, we'd both really appreciate it.

Ben

Comment: The Problem is, that even for the most easy distributions, this integral will have no closed form. For example taking a uniform distribution the integral is $\int_0^b (a/x)^{1/(x-1)}$ which is known to have no closed form.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative insight!  I didn't even think to check that.